# Iteration on a for loop

Tags: angular, loops, typescript, for-loop, rxjs

I am trying to create a search bar based on the data entered by the user.

To do this, I retrieve the data from the user. I create a For loop to iterate on all my threads. Then I compare these two values :

```
threads: BehaviorSubject<{[key: string]: Thread }> = new BehaviorSubject({});

searchUser(): Observable<Thread> {
var str;
var element = document.getElementById('chat-window-input');

if(element != null) {
  str = (element as HTMLInputElement).value;
}
else {
  str = null;
}

return this.threads.map((threadDictionary: {[key: string]: Thread}) => {
  for( let key in threadDictionary ) {
    console.log("key", threadDictionary[key]);

    if(threadDictionary[key].participants[0].name.startsWith(str)) {
      return threadDictionary[key];
    }
  }
});
}
```

I then subscribe to this flow :

```
displaySearchUser(): void {
this.searchUser().subscribe((thread: Thread) => {
  if (thread !== undefined) {
    this.searchArrayThreads.push(thread);
    this.searchThreads.next(this.searchArrayThreads);
  }
});
}
```

Then I post it:

```
<div class="new-chat-window">
  <div class="search-bar">
    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
    <input type="text"
           class="new-chat-window-input"
           name="chat-window-input"
           id="chat-window-input"
           placeholder="Rechercher"
           (keyup)="threadService.displaySearchUser()"/>
  </div>

  <div class="list-container">
    <list-user
      *ngFor="let thread of threadService.searchThreads | async"
      [thread]="thread">
    </list-user>
  </div>
</div>
```

My problem is that I only get on the last item. When I display `'threadDictionnary [key]'` in my console, it never changes.

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
EDIT
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

I am editing my POST with some details. When I run my `this.displaySearchUser ()` function in my constructor loop, this is good on the 3 different elements.

May I run it a second time, this iterates only on one element.

Here is a picture of my console; the first 4 lines correspond to the first launch of my function.
Then the next line corresponds to the second run of my function : 
[image]